# Ошибка при проверке плоскости контуров: Assertion failed npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'cv::contourArea'

Tags: python, opencv, информатика

Вот полный текст ошибки:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\shapedescr.cpp:315: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'cv::contourArea'

Вот мой код:

```
# OpenCV #
import cv2
import numpy

# Data Load
image = cv2.imread(r"D:\Vladyslav Kryvoruchko\HW - Home Work Maker\hw\scaner\shaded.png")

# Black Like Image
black = numpy.zeros_like(image)

# Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
ret2, th2 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# I copied this from stackoverflow
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
threshed = cv2.morphologyEx(th2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Contuors
imgContours, Contours = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for contour in Contours:

    # Checking contors area
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 200:

        # Coordinates Of Symbols
        [X, Y, W, H] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

        # Bounding Boxes
        cv2.rectangle(image, (X, Y), (X + W, Y + H), (0,0,255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(black, (X, Y), (X + W, Y + H), (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imshow('contour', image)
cv2.imshow('black', black)
```

Как найти символы на изображении я нашел на Stackoverflow. Но ответ там был с багами, я промучился с этим 2 часа. Что я делаю не так?

Помогите, пожалуйста!

PS:
Если я делаю совсем что-то не то, то перепишите мой код пожалуйста!
Моя цель: найти символы на изображении, и потом сохранить их в отдельные файлы для дальнейшей обработки.

Comment: Помоему тут перепутаны `imgContours, Contours`, попробуйте: `Contours, imgContours = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`, т.к. если судить по описанию функции в документации https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0 возвращаются такие параметры: `contours, hierarchy`, что подтверждается моим кодом по поиску книг https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/opencv__examples/Finding%20books%20in%20images/main.py#L33 :)